# Did Billy's power get diluted?

Tags: dc-extended-universe, shazam

Through out the movie *Shazam!* (2019), we see the bad guy, Dr. Sivana, wanting Billy to touch the staff and say his name (Shazam) so that the power would go to Dr. Sivana. At some point, Billy shared his powers with his family using the same method (touching the staff and saying his name).

So did Billy's powers get diluted, or did everyone get the full power of Shazam? What would have happened if Billy had done as Dr. Sivana told him? Would Billy have lost all of his power, or only shared it with Dr. Sivana as he did his family?

Comment: @BlueMoon93 Looks like you're correct, it did not come up in my search.

Comment: You may want to close the question then